# Trust relationship issues in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

In there anyway to **remotely** resolve the issue when user getting trust relationship issue between primary domain and a workstation in windows 7?

Comment: Your question is very vague. What kind of trust are you talking about and what is the issue? Do you get any error message? Is this a user right problem?

Comment: a user updated his windows 7, now he can't login into his profile and getting this message saying there is a trust relationship issue. The pc is already joined to the existing Domain. The point is, he does not have the local admin password, and I can't give him the password.

Comment: There are *a lot* of different things that can cause trust relationship errors between a client and the DCs. I think you need to isolate exactly what is causing the error before we can offer advice on whether or not it can be fixed remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a problem like this occurs, the simplest way is usually to delete the client from the domain and then rejoining it. But as I understand, the client in this case is not easily accessible for the admin. In that case you can use the built in Remote Desktop utility, provided that the mentioned trust issue doesn't prevent RDP from working properly. If it's not activated or working or you don't have any other way of remoting in, than I'm afraid that the only proper solution is for an admin to actually be on place.

Answer (score 0):

You could try resetting the computer account in AD Users & computers right-click -> reset

Comment: No resetting the computer did not resolve the issue.